# How does Cron affect the Getopt::Long module?

Tags: perl, unix, cron

I've written a wrapper program for mailx using perl that allows me to easily add attachments and do some other nifty things that were a little frustrating to accomplish with mailx.

In the first few lines I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ( $to, $from, $subject, $attachments, $body, $file ) = (undef) x 7;

GetOptions(
    "to=s"          => \$to,
    "from=s"        => \$from,
    "subject=s"     => \$subject,
    "attachments=s" => \$attachments,
    "body=s"        => \$body,
    "file=s"        => \$file,
);
$to      = getlogin unless $to;
$from    = getlogin unless $from;
$subject = " "      unless $subject;
```

This wrapper up until now has worked fine when being called by other scripts. However now that we have a script being run by the Cron some funny things are happening. This Cron job calls the wrapper by only specifying -t and -su but omitting -fr (yes abbreviations of the flags are being used). The resulting email correctly sets the To: however has the Sender listed as -s@blah.com with the subject line blank. As per the above code I can only assume that there is something strange going between Cron and the Getopt::Long module. Does anyone know why a Cron job may cause this odd behavior? If it is something else that is wrong what would it be?

Comment: `(undef) x 7` is clever, but undef is the default value for new scalar variable declarations, so there's no need for it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl's `getlogin` probably doesn't return anything useful from cron, quoting from `getlogin(3)`:

```
   getlogin() returns a pointer to a string containing
   the name of the user logged in on the controlling
   terminal of the process, or a null pointer if this
   information cannot be determined.
```

I suggest changing your crontab to always include the username explicitly for any options that rely on `getlogin`. You could also change your wrapper to use `getpwuid($<)`. (See `perlvar(1)` and `perlfunc(1)` for details on `$<` and `getpwuid`.)

Why that screws up your mailx, I don't know, but I'm going to guess you're using backticks, `exec` or `system` with a string to start mailx, rather than `exec` or `system` with a list.

Comment: this is my open to mailx:
open( MAILX, "|$_mailx -t -r $from -s \"$subject\"" )

I like the suggestions, but even if I do get a null pointer from getlogin() shouldn't the subject still be set properly?

Comment: perlfunc suggests the idiom:  `$login = getlogin || getpwuid($<) || "Kilroy";`

Comment: @stocherilac, your command is being run as `mailx -t -r -s <subject>`. The `-s` switch appears to be interpreted as part of an email address because it immediately follows `-r`.